# Diffent voltage on each side of bus bar

Tags: electrical

Having trouble with lights in my barn some are dim some really bright checked bus bars in panel one side is 89 volts other is 159 volts

Comment: How many wires are running to the barn?

Answer (score 11):

### Classic "lost neutral"

They are different, but add up to around 240v... That is the classic symptom of a loose or open neutral in your cable or more likely, its terminations.

Hot to hot, the voltage is 240V.  You have two sides of 120V with neutral in the middle.  If the neutral is working, it forces each side to 120V.  If the neutral is lost, then the two sides are simply in series, and they will add to "whatever" based on the loading on each side.

This can be quite destructive to equipment and even start a fire.   I would shut off everything (240V-only loads are OK) until you can fix it.

Also, if one terminal is failing, possibly others are too.  When you find the problem, check the two hots and ground also.

### Or it could be *no* neutral

In older installations, we sometimes see *really dumb* setups like 2-wire 120V circuits converted to 240V by trying to use the local ground rod *as* the neutral.  *This doesn't work.* Dirt doesn't conduct electricity very well. It can't function as a "current return".  This acts like a "lost neutral", energizing the neutral *and the ground* to hazardous voltages. Not good.  In this case, it might have been like this *all along* and you only just noticed, or soil conditions changed where it's not returning as well as it used to.

This *entire* type of setup needs to be taken out of service ASAP.  Convert it to 120V only, convert it to 240V-only (no neutral in use - easier than ever now that many lights are 120/240/277), or use a transformer to convert it into its own main service.

Comment: Can there be a slight but persistent difference in the two legs at the service entrance with no adverse affect, e.g., 119 V on one side and 121 V? Or is any difference greater than measurement error an indication of a fault in one of the two hots coming from the transformer?

Comment: Sure, small differences would reflect ordinary load imbalance.  You are probably not the only user of that transformer.